# Xampp - access from external IP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, ip

I installed xampp v3.2.3 with PHP 7.2.18 on my windows 10 and I can view xampp and the site locally with my IP address.

I am trying to have my site viewed in XAMPP from an external device but I am not succeeding.
At the moment the changes I made are these:

1) Modified the httpd.conf file:

*Listen XXX.XX.X.XX:80
Listen XXX.XX.X.XX:8080
Require all granted
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from XXX.XX.X.XX (IP address of the external PC)*

2) Modified the httpd.conf file

*All "Required local" have been replaced in "Require all granted"*

3) Created the new rule on my PC to allow access to my PC from external computers with port 80.
Finally I entered my IP in the DMZ field of my router.

Unfortunately, my PC's xampp is not reachable from an external device.

What else can i do?

Comment: Did you give XAMPP a public IP address? If not, only computers on your network can access it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried to give the public IP address given by my provider but every time I try to launch it it gives me the page of my provider...

Comment: That is something you should discuss with your provider.

Comment: Is there a way to send my public IP to xampp or do I have to contact my provider?

Comment: Look at the question I linked above.

Comment: Thanks man, i read it but not explain how use my public IP for view xampp in a external device..